# How to print a file from VS Code?

Tags: printing, visual-studio-code

I want to send the file I'm currently editing to a printer, like I did in Notepad++ for example.
I havn't found any hint on a print command. Is it not possible ?

Comment: The first editor without a Print command. And I have used many editors . . .

Comment: You can do just about everything from VSCode -- if you install the right plugin.

Comment: @Roland is for them to ensure all of us buy MS-Word, I guess... =P

Comment: @Roland Sublime also lacks printing. If you ask me VS Code is basically a (better) knockoff of Sublime.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

It is not yet available, but I found an issue report for VS Code for that feature.

It's currently in the backlog, so we can expect it soon.

[Support to print the editor contents #5953](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/5953)

Edit:
In the meantime, you can use this extension:

- [Print - by PD Consulting](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pdconsec.vscode-print)

Comment: As of 09/15/2020, 'soon' seems still far away. Instead the aforementioned extensions, pretty sad.

Comment: As of Nov 25, 2021, 'soon' is still far away.

Comment: Three years on...

Comment: Any simple github addons?

Comment: It's 2022 and the issue is still open :D

Comment: Hello from 2023 .. we are still expecting it soon™

Comment: Hello from 05/2023, 'soon' is next decade?

Comment: June 2023 now, the issue is still open, and `nobuhito.printcode` is now deprecated. (replaced by `pdconsec.vscode-print`)

Comment: Jan 2024, still waiting...

Answer (score 44):

Now you can install addon for VS Code - search "[PrintCode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nobuhito.printcode)".

Note that the repository for this extension was last updated in February 2018 with numerous issues outstanding.

Comment: Another option: [PolaCode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pnp.polacode)

Comment: stock install and it using chrome my default browser produces a corrupt pdf from a php file that has php, htm and js. (only missing style/css tag)

Comment: @Angry84 the problem you describe has nothing to do with the extension. By the time you save a PDF, rendering as HTML is complete and control has passed to your web browser.

Comment: Now depreciated. Use Print extension instead.

Comment: PrintCode extension has been deprecated, use [Print](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pdconsec.vscode-print) extension instead.

Answer (score 26):

I found the PrintCode extension inspiring but unfinished and with a number of flaws. In particular it depends on a specific paper size to wrap and as a result does not respond well if you change paper size or orientation in the print dialog.

It's open source so I looked at the code and didn't like that either. No programmer *ever* likes another's coding style. So I pinched the idea of using a web-browser as platform driver for HTML printing -- my hat is off to the PrintCode author for that cunning insight -- and wrote my own.

In the process I fixed all the known bugs, added everything on my wishlist and a couple of things suggested by others. The biggest thing was figuring out the CSS required to respect print dialog paper size and orientation. This also sorts out the mysterious disappearing line numbers problem, although I'm not sure why. The next biggest thing was learning to probe for an unused port, a problem that also afflicts PrintCode causing the browser to open showing no content.

### Major issues

- PrintCode depends on a web service. You can't use it offline.
- Many people want to be able to open a file, select a portion and print just the selection.
- The print dialog supports changing paper size and orientation. This clashes with the way PrintCode works.
- Some people like to run multiple VS Code windows.
- When you print a markdown file, you probably don't want it printed like a text file when it can be rendered with fonts and proper headings and bullets etc.
- Support is required for remote workspaces.

Because each instance of VS Code needs a different port for its embedded webserver, you can't just use a setting. Dynamic port allocation is necessary.

Remote workspaces weren't even a thing until two years after maintenance ceased on PrintCode.

If you want to survey your options, get onto [Visual Studio Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com), choose the Visual Studio Code tab and search for `printing`.

If you just want a link to my version, it's here:

[Print - by PD Consulting](http://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pdconsec.vscode-print).

If you like what you see but need something I haven't thought of, the marketplace page has a link to the repo on GitHub. Create an issue and tell me what you need -- or write it yourself and submit a PR.

Comment: Hope you will put yours in the marketplace or find some other way to share it!

Comment: I _have_ put it in the marketplace. Direct linking to my own work seemed a bit close to spam. Since you are specifically asking for my version, here it is: http://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pdconsec.vscode-print

Comment: @NatKuhn see comment above

Comment: thank you! I had actually followed your instructions, but when I searched for `print` I found 12 extensions, none of which had your name on it. So your direct link was helpful, and now I know that searching for `"vs code printing"` also works.

Comment: As long as you disclose your affiliation, it's perfectly fine to include a direct link in your answer.

Answer (score 7):

Now there is an extension available for printing from the VS Code Editor.
It's called **VS Code Printing Free**.
I've tried it for a couple of days and it works fine.

Comment: VS Code Printing Free by Peter Wone, i.e., the answer above this one.

Comment: I've shortened the name to just *Print*

Comment: Yes is shortened to Print . Woked OK for me first try.

Answer (score 4):

Poor man's answer: Copy code to Notepad2 or Notepad++ and print from there.
The colour coding will be different though

Comment: Same as in Sublime Text. 

Answer (score 1):

PrintCode has been deprecated. We can now use [Print](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pdconsec.vscode-print) extension which include a nice icon button on the file, which generates the code output with file name and line numbers, which are neat.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pdconsec.vscode-print. If you change the values that I have marked in the picture in the extension settings a browser tab opens with the you can then print this also works on the Ipad. It works also with the code-server Version inside a Docker Container.
I put the file on github https://github.com/chrishdx/vsc-print

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwgA9.png)

Answer (score 0):

Install the "print" extension, then right-click and choose print.

The "printCode" extension is deprecated.

Answer (score -1):

You can use an Extension of VS Code: PrintCode

1. Install extension PrintCode
2. On Mac: command + shift + P
3. choose command> PrintCode

Comment: Did you read any of the above answers?