# How to print files in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I tried to print a file from Visual Studio Code, but could neither find an entry in the menu nor an extension.

I'm using Version 1.4.0 from August 4th, 2016.

I ended up opening the file in Notepad++ for printing, which is quite cumbersome.

Comment: tried with `Apple+P` or `Strg+P`? (dependent on your OS)

Comment: Ctrl+P opens the file finder on Windows. Pretty much the same as Ctrl+Shift+P which opens the command bar but without an already entered ">".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print a file from VsCode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36934247/how-to-print-a-file-from-vscode)

Comment: Duplicate of above link.

Answer (score 26):

Still no builtin print functionality to date, but there's a `PrintCode` extension for this.

Edit 09 jan 2024:

as @Dutchie432 commented, "`PrintCode` is deprecated and replaced with an extension simply called `Print`"

Comment: PrintCode prints beautifully. Install PrintCode. Reload. Press F1 and type Printcode.

Comment: Just a quick note on this, PrintCode is deprecated and replaced with an extension simply called "Print"

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately seems that until today (09/23) there's still no functionality provided -I came to the same cumbersome surprise this morning just like you did last month. Moreover, seems that other simpler IDE/ISE tools from MS lack the same functionality :-( See powershell_ise screenshot.
[image: ps_ise_no_print]
Something the MS guys forgot to tell us -like upgrading ($$) in  order to print? btw, In [this post](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/56cf73f1-ae33-42fa-8dc4-1e739f0da83a/hey-scripting-guy-how-do-i-print-a-powershell-script-from-ise?forum=ITCG) I found how to do that in the ps_ise.

Good luck.

Comment: Aug 2018 and this basic functionality still isn't there.  Which is pathetic.  MS was so excited about copying Sublime they left out the ONE thing that keeps Sublime from being perfect.  NO PRINTING.  Basic printing has been around since the dawn of computers.  Shame on you Microsoft and shame on you Sublime Text.

Comment: Nov 2020 and printing STILL doesn't seem to be available as built-in functionality. How did Microsoft manage to decide that printing wasn't something valuable in an IDE? The mind boggles....

Comment: For _Visual Studio Code_, the situation is slightly better thanks to efforts from the community (e.g. [Printcode](https://printcode.launchaco.com/))

Comment: [PrintCode](https://printcode.launchaco.com) does not seem to work

Comment: PrintCode was deprecated, but there is now a "Print" Extension.

Answer (score 6):

There is now a Visual Studio Code Marketplace extension called [Print](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pdconsec.vscode-print) that allows you to print formatted code and brings up the system dialogue for printing the file. It nicely adds the button for printing to the existing GUI in an intuitive way.

Answer (score 5):

One way to print your code is to push it to an online version control system like Github or Bitbucket. In your browser, navigate to the file and print it.

Doing it this way, you'll get syntax highlighting and version control.

Comment: That's a very practical suggestion. I was all ready to write a VS Code extension to use some other work I just did to support network printing for SPAs, but your idea is so simple I don't think I'll bother!

Comment: I changed my mind and wrote an extension because it was the only way to support all the mod cons like printing a selection with line numbers that match the editor. If you want to survey your options get onto https://marketplace.visualstudio.com, click the VS Code tab and search for print. If you're trying to find mine, it isn't listed under my name, it's called "VS Code Printing",

Answer (score 0):

Cut and paste into MS Word.  All of the colors are preserved.  Then print from there.

Answer (score -16):

Highlight your code and hit "Ctrl + P"

Comment: Have you actually tried that in Visual Studio Code?